# How to interpret the logic of an "or" in a matrix proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I am trying to learn to better interpret the meaning of equations and that is the purpose of this question, not just to find the proof, but to find the logical flow of the proof and understand it.

I want to prove or disprove that if A and B are both n x n matrices and $A^2B^2 = (AB)^2$ then $AB = BA$

First I can try expanding and set equality to find a contradictory term.

$AABB = ABAB$

A solution for this would be for $AB = BA$.

However there is another possibility:

$A^2 == A$

$B^2 == B$

AND

$(BA==B)$     OR        $(BA==A)$

So in terms of the logical thought process regarding this proof I must realize that I cannot prove something until I have pursued all routes of possibilities (disproving is much easier). So I continue, but I am a little confused as to how to interpret the OR statement? I am also a programmer so I am familiar with the clause, but I'm unfamiliar with actually coming to an OR statement in a proof. The reason I got the OR statement was because the initial statement $A^2B^2=(AB)^2$ if A and B are idempotent AND either $BA==A$ OR $BA==B$.

*1. How can I create a logical flow from these boolean logical terms? How do I interpret **OR** statements in a proof?*

I went on to try both cases and I found that for the proof $AB=BA$ to be true

**IF** $BA==A$ **THEN**
$AB==A$

**ELSE IF**  $BA==B$ **THEN**
$AB==B$

My problem is that I don't see the flaw in the logic. I know definitively that this does not work unless A and B are the same idempotent matrix. **This is FALSE** since for idempotent matrices the first conditions may be true, but AB doesn't equal BA.

2. Do both of the OR cases have to be true **at the same time** for this proof to be true? What should I do and how should I think about it?

Please provide answers with respect to the interpretation of logic and how to improve the flow of logic.

Comment: It's not clear at all why you'd say "It seems like..." It's obvious from the previous that *if* $AB=BA$ then $A^2B^2=(AB)^2$. But the opposite does not "seem like" it is true. If $A,B$ are invertible, however, you can easily show it is true.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The reason I say "seems like" is because the proof is actually false. If A and B are idempotent matrices such that A^2 = A and B^2 = B. Then the first set of conditions are true, but A*B does not equal B*A.

Comment: Right, but it doesn't even "seem like" to me. You are confusing implications - just because it is obvious that if $AB=BA$ then $A^2B^2=(AB)^2$, doesn't mean that the opposite implication in remotely expected.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, my apologies, I wrote that poorly. Let me edit the post.

Comment: @Klik : Why do you write $A*B$ for matrix multiplication?  Just $AB$ is enough but if you must have a symbol for the binary operation you can write $A\cdot B$ or $A\times B$ or any of several other things. If the Queen hosts a state dinner at Buckingham Palace and you're among the guests, do you eat mashed potatoes by shoving your face into the plate when silverware is available?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Op. Sorry. Didn't realize I was among royalty. Hahaha, point well put--I'll change it. Please, consider providing an answer :).